# Transform/Remove Cross Join in Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sequelize.js, cross-join

Ive got this MsSql

```
SELECT k._id,
       coalesce(NULLIF(v1.value,''), NULLIF(v2.value,''), k.name) valueWithFallback,
FROM [Keys] k
INNER JOIN [ProductKeys] pk ON pk.key_id = k._id
INNER JOIN [Products] prod ON pk.product_id = prod._id
AND prod._id IN (2)
CROSS JOIN [Langs] l1
LEFT JOIN [Values] v1 ON k._id = v1.key_id
AND l1._id = v1.lang_id
LEFT JOIN [Values] v2 ON k._id = v2.key_id
AND v2.lang_id = 75
WHERE l1.pp_id IN (7,
                   9)
```

But I have to do this without an `Cross Join`, because my Circumstances dont allow to. With that I mean I cant use the Command `CROSS JOIN` only Left/Inner Join.
How could I Transform this for the same Result with Left/Inner Join?
Ive found somewhere that mentions a Cross Join is an Inner Join without Condition so Ive tried with an Inner like this.

```
SELECT [dict_Keys].[_id],
       coalesce(NULLIF([value1].[value], ''), NULLIF([value2].[value], ''), [dict_Keys].[name]) AS [fallBack],
FROM [Keys]AS [dict_Keys]
INNER JOIN ([ProductKeys] AS [Products.ProductKeys]
            INNER JOIN [Products] AS [Products] ON [Products].[_id] = [Products.ProductKeys].[product_id]
            AND [Products.ProductKeys].[product_id] IN (2)) ON [dict_Keys].[_id] = [Products.ProductKeys].[key_id]
LEFT JOIN [Values] AS [value1] ON [dict_Keys].[_id] = [value1].[key_id]
INNER JOIN [Langs] AS [value1.dict_Lang] ON [value1].[lang_id] = [value1.dict_Lang].[_id]
LEFT JOIN [Values] AS [value2] ON [dict_Keys].[_id] = [value2].[key_id]
AND [value2].lang_id = 75
WHERE [value1.dict_Lang].pp_id IN (7,
                                   9)
ORDER BY [value1.dict_Lang].[pp_id],
         [name];
```

The first Query is which is working with MsSql. The second is generated by Sequelize which cant Produce Cross join, as mentioned only Left/Inner Join.

**Edit1:**
Maybe a Fully another Query could help here.
So what I want to Achieve is to Export some `Keys`. For every Key should be a Translation, in the Case there is no Translation a Fallback shall happen. For this case is the `coalesce..` which writes first the English Translation, if there is none, it writes just the KeyName, so never Null Values happen.
This Keys are related to a Product.
So I need a Query :

```
// get me the Key Id
SELECT k._id,
// Get me the Value to this Key. If there is none for the Selected Lang get the Default = 75, if this is not as well there wirte just the KeyName
       coalesce(NULLIF(v1.value,''), NULLIF(v2.value,''), k.name) valueWithFallback,
// Get me all Keys
FROM [Keys] k
// Which belongs to this selected Product
INNER JOIN [ProductKeys] pk ON pk.key_id = k._id
// through n:m Table ProductKey
INNER JOIN [Products] prod ON pk.product_id = prod._id
// Selected Product
AND prod._id IN (2)
// for Fallback
CROSS JOIN [Langs] l1
// get me the Value to the selected Lang
LEFT JOIN [Values] v1 ON k._id = v1.key_id
AND l1._id = v1.lang_id
// If null for this selected Language get the Default
LEFT JOIN [Values] v2 ON k._id = v2.key_id
AND v2.lang_id = 75
// The selected Languages in which I want to export
WHERE l1.pp_id IN (7,
                       9)
```

This actually work with the First MsSql Query with Cross join. Could another Query without Cross Join do the same Result?

**Edit2:**

**Table:** `Key`

```
x---------------------x
|  _Id     |  Name    | 
x----------|----------|
|    1     |     Hello|
|    2     |     Test |
x---------------------x
```

**Table:** `Value`

```
x----------------------------------------x
|  _id  |    key_id   | lang_id| value   | 
x---------|-----------|------------------x            
|    1    |     1     |    73  | Dehello | 
|    2    |     2     |    73  | DeTest  |
x-----------------------------------------x
```

**Table:** `Lang`

```
x---------------------------x
|  _id    |  pp_id    | code| 
x---------|-----------|-----|
|    73   |     7     | de  |  
|    75   |     9     | en  | 
x---------------------------x
```

With the `cross join` my Result was:
**Result**

```
x-----------------------x
|  key_Id  |  value     | 
x----------|------------|
|    1     |     Hello  |
|    2     |     Test   |
|    1     |     DEHello|
|    2     |     DETest |
x-----------------------x
```

I got all Keys which belongs to selected Product(Product Table Example missing because I think the Problem does not lies there). As asked get me all `Values` with `pp_id` through `Langs Table`, **ResultTable as -> DEHello**. If there is no `value` in the `Value table` for an asked `pp_id` then do me the `Fallback->coalesce`,**ResultTable as -> Hello**. I hope this Helps a further bit for my needs.
As the answers by Hogan either gave me **all** `values` without respecting the `pp_id IN(7,9)` or giving me **only** the `values` where `pp_id in (7,9)` exists and not doing the `Fallback`.

Comment: You can try `INNER JOIN [Langs] AS [value1.dict_Lang] ON 1=1`

Comment: Don't know what *circumstances don't allow to use `CROSS JOIN`*, but if you need the same effect without this code you'd reach this with `SELECT * FROM tblA,tblB`. In both cases you'd get the *cartesian product* (*each-with-each*). There are reasons to prefer `CROSS JOIN` actually...

Comment: This sounds like a very strange artificial requirement. CROSS JOIN is the correct thing here.

Comment: @SeanLange -- not really, because of the where statement (`WHERE l1.pp_id IN`...) it is not really a true "cross join"

Comment: I know that it is. But as mentioned Sequelize dont Support it or has the Command Cross Join. The question is not should I change or is Cross join here better. Its about to get the same result without the Command Cross Join. But the Same Logic.

Comment: @AkAk47 -- I've no idea what you mean by that comment.

Comment: @Hogan it was for SeanLange who told to use Cross Join.

Comment: Without reading all details, `A CROSS JOIN B` is the same as `A INNER JOIN B ON 1=1`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov This seems at the moment to be working. Going to try some different test with that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments below you **don't want a cross join** you want an inner join.  By adding the criteria to the where statement you were limiting your results to be the same as an inner join. Run the following code to see I'm correct.

```
SELECT k._id,
       coalesce(NULLIF(v1.value,''), NULLIF(v2.value,''), k.name) valueWithFallback,
FROM [Keys] k
INNER JOIN [ProductKeys] pk ON pk.key_id = k._id
INNER JOIN [Products] prod ON pk.product_id = prod._idAND prod._id IN (2)
INNER JOIN [Values] v1 ON k._id = v1.key_id 
INNER JOIN [Langs] l1 ON l1._id = v1.lang_id and l1.pp_id IN (7, 9)
LEFT JOIN [Values] v2 ON k._id = v2.key_id AND v2.lang_id = 75
```

To get back to our miss-understanding in comments -- My query was limiting the [Langs] table to 7 and 9 -- but it was not limiting the other tables to 7 and 9 -- this is the definition of an inner join -- restricting other tables to only including the rows that join to your table is an inner join.  A cross join is *the exact reverse of this*.  Clearly (as I've been saying) it is the case you don't want the functionality of a cross join, so you should not be trying to "make a cross join work".

---

*original answer*

```
SELECT k._id,
       coalesce(NULLIF(v1.value,''), NULLIF(v2.value,''), k.name) valueWithFallback,
FROM [Keys] k
INNER JOIN [ProductKeys] pk ON pk.key_id = k._id
INNER JOIN [Products] prod ON pk.product_id = prod._idAND prod._id IN (2)
LEFT JOIN [Values] v1 ON k._id = v1.key_id 
LEFT JOIN [Langs] l1 ON l1._id = v1.lang_id and l1.pp_id IN (7, 9)
LEFT JOIN [Values] v2 ON k._id = v2.key_id AND v2.lang_id = 75
```

Comment: This seems not to Respect the `l1.pp_id IN (7,9)` because it Joins every Langs and not only the ones with the `pp_id` 7/9

Comment: @AkAk47 are you saying your platform does not process this correctly?

Comment: The Result is wrong. With my Cross Query I get only Keys with the Values with the Selected Lang. With Your Code it gives me for Selected Keys every Value for every Language and not only the Selected ones. So I think it is not Checking the `l1.pp_id IN (7,9)` correctly? Maybe my Edit gives you a hint what I actually want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry Ive got no Notification that you updated your answer. At the moment it seems your Query is going in the right Direction, but still missing to `include/JOIN-> NULL Values` so the Fallback with Coalesce is not working. But as I can see you want to say I cant get the "Functionality" of a `Cross Join` through compensating with `Inner Join` or similar Joins?

Comment: I as well did a Second Edit with Table examples in Hope they represent more my Problem. If not fully understandable pls comment and I will try to change it.